# An employee departing means that our project spend is reduced as that employee gets deleted. How to ethically arrange departures?

Tags: management

I work for a very metric driven organization and they have time tracking and budgeting for everything. However, they also like to hire people without experience to let them "grow" into their roles. That is how we end up in the following situation.

In our company, projects are very strictly budgeted. We can have a million dollar budget for a project, which means that work stops as soon as we hit that target based on employee hours allocation and billing rates.

However, that system is tied to our primary HR system in such a way that when an employee leaves, all their billing records get deleted as there is no counterpart in the HR system.

For example, say that an employee racks up $50,000 in billable hours on a project on a project with a $250,000 budget. If there are 5 equivalent employees working at the same time, the project hits its budget. But if one employee suddenly leaves, the project goes to $200,000, as that employee no longer exists.

What is even better is that we get the surplus of the budget as a bonus.  So when that one person left, the other four members of the team each got $12,500.

It is generally pro-rated to salary, but that is the basic concept.

I am a manager and I like my bonuses. So do my other employees. I am looking for ways to encourage a high rate of churn in a fairly regular way so we can keep getting these absurdly sized bonuses without firing someone every project. I want them to have great opportunities to leave instead.

Comment: How averse are you to false moustaches?

Comment: A truly Dilbertesque script!

Comment: The answer is: there is no ethical way. This is unethical to its core.

Comment: Deleting billing records for people who have billed time smells like fraud.

Comment: I smell the pungent odour of ... trolls.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we do not give advice on how to engage in fraudulent activities.

Comment: @Kilisi I am not editing the database. How is it fraud?

Comment: @LaconicDroid the records aren't deleted. There is just a faulty reporting script that first gets the employee IDs and then groups their time entries in the database by project.

Comment: @advew - You do understand it will only take one or two times until someone figures everything out.  I would even go as far to say anyone who profited from such a scheme would have to pay back the company.  Please don’t steal from the company by making it “unpleasant” for other people.

Comment: Have you actually seen this bonus-from-departing-employee happen, for real? Have you seen it happen more than once? How many occurrences, over how long a span of time?

Comment: @advew - so you mean nobody in the "metrics driven" accounting department has noticed the overspend when the $50k of employee billables is added to the $50k paid in bonuses, but has only been reported as $50k?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is hilarious. Your management is metric driven to the point of missing obvious errors in the data.

1. **Have a networking and growth budget**

I assume that projects are what? 4-6 months in length at least? You have 5 developers. So you need the team to turnover ever 2 years or so, which is quite typical for developers anyway, but if you want them to be leaving on a fairly regular pace, give each of them a networking and growth budget if possible.

Let them expense networking lunches, spend time on Leetcode practice, take time off to go to conferences, etc. As long as your projects aren't a month in length, all you need is a fairly regular rate of dev turnover.

2. **Proactively send them opportunities from your network.**

Any reason not to send them opportunities that might interest them from your own network? Buy a favour down the line. If you were open about your willingness to accept high turnover, it could allow for you to shuffle people elsewhere into your network as your alumni. Just stress that you prefer departures to be around project completion dates and will work with them to make it happen and be very clear about when those dates will be.

3. **Have a steady intern stream.**

You need people to be deleted from the HR system right? So get an intern for each project, bill them accordingly, and they will naturally depart. Won't be as large a bonus, but could be done very consistently.